# How to add an input to a radiobutton selection in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am pretty new to Shiny and for the app I am building, I need to add an input to a `radioButton` selection.

This is the code for my `radioButton`:

```
values <- c("Carbs" = "carbs", "Proteins" = "prots", "BMI" = "bmi"),
radioButtons("plotVal", "What value do you want to plot?", choices = values)
```

I would like to add an input field. If the user doesn't find the right choice, he could enter his own value. The end result would be something like that:

> What value do you want to plot?
>
> O Carbs
>
> O Proteins
>
> O BMI
>
> O [Other...   ]

The [Other... ] choice would be a `textInput`.

I've searched the web and read all the tutorials for inputs that I found but I didn't find this specific case of figure. Can anyone help me out? Thank you.

Comment: I would include "Other" as you did and you can add a conditionnal pannel to display a text input to fill in by the user if "Other" is selected. It is two components but it is probably the easiest to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `updateRadioButtons`:

```
library(shiny)

values <- c("Carbs" = "carbs", "Proteins" = "prots", "BMI" = "bmi")

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("plotVal", "What value do you want to plot?", choices = values),
  textInput("other", "Type in additional category"),
  actionButton("add", "Add category")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    req(input$other)
    otherVal <- "other"
    names(otherVal) <- input$other
    updatedValues <- c(values, otherVal)
    updateRadioButtons(session, "plotVal", choices = updatedValues)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```